# Web method to return simple string using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

Having trouble getting a simple string to return from the server using an ajax call. I'm not getting a 404 on the ajax, but a 200, statusText: "OK".

I am getting the full page HTML returned, and it is falling into the error block.

I have edited the config to contain:

```
<jsonSerializationmaxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
```

Here is my AJAX:

```js
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: $(location).attr('href') + "/GetYard",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
});
function OnSuccess(response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

And my VB.Net code:

```
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function GetYard() As String

    Return "TEST"
    'HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = True
    'HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
    'HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Test")
    'HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
End Function
```

Comment: A 200 response code wouldn't be "falling into the error block".  Are you *sure* that's what's happening?  What debugging have you done to confirm this?  If the `error` callback is indeed being invoked then you're getting something other than a `200`.

Comment: @David when i check on google chrome debugger, i get Satus Code: 200 OK but the breakpoin on the error alert is being hit

Comment: If you set `dataType: "json",` and your response is not JSON the error function will be called instead of the success

Comment: Change the method to `POST`

Comment: @Musa this works, as in it goes into the onsuccess block, but the response text is the page HTML

Answer (score 0):

This requires the [EnablePageMethods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepagemethods(v=vs.110).aspx) option turned on in the script manager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager .. EnablePageMethods="True" />
```

If you read the HTML returned form the onsuccess (referring to your comment) it, it's probably saying you need to turn on EnablePageMethods, or some other configuration option.

Make sure that is done; here is also an [online example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) but it appears your approach mirrors that, other than the fact that it uses "POST" as the type and not "GET".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have set `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">` in Site.Master

Comment: unfortunately it didn't, sorry I miss worded my response

Comment: Are you still getting an HTML response?  Usually that contains the results of the error...